# How to achieve the multi select items from the drop-down or list in react js web

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-multiselect

hello friend i am new in react js web. I want to select multiple cities from the drop-down or list like this.[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVgwx.jpg)

and after selecting multiple cities user click on apply and then cites looks like this[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sYY6z.png)

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have provided an example using material ui. Please check it.

```
import React from 'react';
import {makeStyles, useTheme} from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import Input from '@material-ui/core/Input';
import InputLabel from '@material-ui/core/InputLabel';
import MenuItem from '@material-ui/core/MenuItem';
import FormControl from '@material-ui/core/FormControl';
import ListItemText from '@material-ui/core/ListItemText';
import Select from '@material-ui/core/Select';
import Checkbox from '@material-ui/core/Checkbox';

const useStyles = makeStyles((theme) => ({
    formControl: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        minWidth: 120,
        maxWidth: 300,
    },
    chips: {
        display: 'flex',
        flexWrap: 'wrap',
    },
    chip: {
        margin: 2,
    },
    noLabel: {
        marginTop: theme.spacing(3),
    },
}));

const ITEM_HEIGHT = 48;
const ITEM_PADDING_TOP = 8;
const MenuProps = {
    PaperProps: {
        style: {
            maxHeight: ITEM_HEIGHT * 4.5 + ITEM_PADDING_TOP,
            width: 250,
        },
    },
};

const names = [
    'Oliver Hansen',
    'Van Henry',
    'April Tucker',
    'Ralph Hubbard',
    'Omar Alexander',
    'Carlos Abbott',
    'Miriam Wagner',
    'Bradley Wilkerson',
    'Virginia Andrews',
    'Kelly Snyder',
];

function getStyles(name, personName, theme) {
    return {
        fontWeight:
            personName.indexOf(name) === -1
                ? theme.typography.fontWeightRegular
                : theme.typography.fontWeightMedium,
    };
}

export default function MultipleSelect() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const theme = useTheme();
    const [personName, setPersonName] = React.useState([]);

    const handleChange = (event) => {
        setPersonName(event.target.value);
    };

    return (
        <div>
            <FormControl className={classes.formControl}>
                <InputLabel id="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label">Tag</InputLabel>
                <Select
                    labelId="demo-mutiple-checkbox-label"
                    id="demo-mutiple-checkbox"
                    multiple
                    value={personName}
                    onChange={handleChange}
                    input={<Input/>}
                    renderValue={(selected) => selected.join(', ')}
                    MenuProps={MenuProps}
                >
                    {names.map((name) => (
                        <MenuItem key={name} value={name}>
                            <Checkbox checked={personName.indexOf(name) > -1}/>
                            <ListItemText primary={name}/>
                        </MenuItem>
                    ))}
                </Select>
            </FormControl>
        </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: thanks for your valuable reply. how to set the style for dropdown,menuitem like  hover,selected item background